# Comparing 2 arrays with different lengths

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I wish to compare and update the score if a match is found:

```
One_array[0] = bla
One_array[1] = blabla
One_array[2] = blablabla

Two_array[0] = bla
Two_array[1] = blabla

Score_array[0] = 10
Score_array[1] = 15
Score_array[2] = 1
```

Now here's the php code for doing the comparison:

```
$count = count($One_array);
$Score = 0; //Initialize score

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<=$count;$j++){
    if(isset($Two_array[$i]) == $One_array[$j]){
      $Score = $Score + $Score_array[$j];
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Undefined offset: 2
>   On the line $Score = Score+$Score_array[$j];

Please assist, I also tried to use `isset` on this line, it didn't work

Comment: What's wrong with using functions like the array_intersect_*() functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two loops need different limits, because the arrays are different sizes.

```
$count1 = count($One_array);
$count2 = count($Two_array);
$Score = 0; //Initialize score

for($i=0;$i<$count2;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$count1;$j++)
    {
        if($Two_array[$i] == $One_array[$j])
            {
                $Score = $Score + $Score_array[$j];
            }
    }
}
```

With this, you don't need to use `isset()`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I tried this code out, but now  I get an offset error on if-statement

Comment: `<=` should be `<` in the loop condition. You were going 1 element too far in both loops.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `array_diff()` function in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php instead of creating a compare function on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is pretty self explanatory. The `$Score_array` does not have the index `2` set.

Do a `var_dump` of the array and look at the output to make sure it actually contains what you believe it to contain.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a lot of mistakes in your code with $i and $j, take a better look on them ;)

By the way you should use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) instead of reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$count = count($One_array);
$Score = 0; //Initialize score

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
                            {
                                for($j=0;$j<=$count;$j++)
                                {
                                    if(isset($Two_array[$i]) && isset($One_array[$j]) && $Two_array[$i]==$One_array[$j])
                                        {
                                            $Score = $Score + $Score_array[$j];
                                        }
                                }
                            }
```

your problem was the if part